# How To Use Physics Body In Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, collision-detection

I'm writing a simple Space Invaders type game for school. I'd like to use the physics properties included in Swift for my collision detection, but I've run into some troubles. Although I've written and re-read the code multiple times, it simply does not work. There are no errors nor any results. Since the code is fairly spread throughout my file, I've included my whole GameScene page below. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
//  --------------------------------------------------------
//  | Space Invasion.                                      |
//  | Created by Kyle Herrmann on 2017-04-05.              |
//  | Copyright © 2017 Kyle Herrmann. All rights reserved. |
//  --------------------------------------------------------


//Import the essentials.
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
enum BodyType:UInt32 {
    case userShipBody = 1
    case alienBody = 2
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    //Variables and Declarations.

    //UserShip Variables.
    let moveLeft: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: -20, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
    let moveRight: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 20, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
    var userShipSprite: SKNode = SKNode()
    var tapDetect: Bool = false
    var posX = CGFloat()
    var posY = CGFloat()

    //Sprite Variables.
    var xSpeed = CGFloat(3.5)
    var ySpeed = CGFloat(3.5)
    let alienMoveLeft: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: -3, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
    let alienMoveRight: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 3, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
    let alienMoveDown: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -4.5, duration: 0.1)
    let classicAlien = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "ClassicAlien"))
    var aliens = [SKSpriteNode]()
    var alienAmount = 6
    var displayAliens = true
    var xAliens = -300
    var yAliens = 520
    var rowCount = 5
    var indexMoving = 0
    //Life Variables.
    var lblLife = SKLabelNode()
    var lifeCounter = 3

    //Detect and Save User Tap Location.
    func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint)   {
        tapDetect = true
        posX = pos.x
        posY = pos.y
    }

    //Grab our object(s).
    override func didMove(to view: SKView)  {

        //Life Count Declaration.
        lblLife = self.childNode(withName: "lblLife") as! SKLabelNode!

        //User Ship.
        for node in self.children           {
            if (node.name == "userShip")    {

                userShipSprite = node
    }
        //Set up user ship body for physics.
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        userShipSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.userShipBody.rawValue

    }
        //Add and display given amount of aliens.
        for index in 0...alienAmount - 1 {

            aliens.append(SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "ClassicAlien")))
            //Location
            let newPosition = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xAliens), y: CGFloat(yAliens))
            xAliens += 120
            aliens[index].position = newPosition
            //Display
            self.addChild(aliens[(index)])

            //Set up physics body
            aliens[index].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.alienBody.rawValue

            //New Row
            if index >= rowCount {
                xAliens = -300
                yAliens -= 100
                rowCount += 6
    }
    }
    }

    //Physics collision and so forth.
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.userShipBody.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.alienBody.rawValue {
            print("Death Detected")
            //Change Life.
            lifeCounter -= 1
            lblLife.text = "Lives:\(lifeCounter)"
        }
        else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.userShipBody.rawValue && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.alienBody.rawValue {
            print("Death Detected")
            //Change Life.
            lifeCounter -= 1
            lblLife.text = "Lives:\(lifeCounter)"
        }
        }

    //Detect Touch Release.
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        tapDetect = false
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self))        }
                                                                        }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)   {      

            //Alien Movement.
            if userShipSprite.position.y < aliens[indexMoving].position.y { //Bottom of Map.
                aliens[indexMoving].run(alienMoveDown)
            }
            if userShipSprite.position.x > aliens[indexMoving].position.x { //Right Side of Map.
                aliens[indexMoving].run(alienMoveRight)
            }
            if userShipSprite.position.x < aliens[indexMoving].position.x { //Left Side of Map.
                aliens[indexMoving].run(alienMoveLeft)
            }
            //Check for next alien.
            if aliens[indexMoving].position.y < userShipSprite.position.y {
                aliens[indexMoving].removeFromParent()
                indexMoving += 1
                //Check for end game.
                if indexMoving > alienAmount {
                    xSpeed += 1
                    ySpeed += 1
                    alienAmount += 6
            }
            }

        //Ship Movement.
        if tapDetect == true                            {
            //Prevent off screen movement (Right side)
            if userShipSprite.position.x > 200          {
                userShipSprite.run(moveLeft)
            }
            //Prevent off screen movement (Left side)
            else if userShipSprite.position.x < -200    {
            userShipSprite.run(moveRight)  }
            //Ship movement.
            if posX > 0 && posY < -300                  {
                userShipSprite.run(moveRight)
            }
            else if posX < 0 && posY < -300             {
                userShipSprite.run(moveLeft)
            }
            }
            }


    // We ain't using this stuff right now.

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }
    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    }
    func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

} //End of Class.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have skimmed thru the code. looks good. U just need to a small amount of code to give the contact bitmask and collision bitmask. So under

```
userShipSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.userShipBody.rawValue
```

Add the code below

```
userShipSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.alienBody.rawValue
userShipSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.alienBody.rawValue
```

AND for the Alien

```
aliens[index].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.alienBody.rawValue
```

Add the codes below because you want it to collide with and also detect contact.

```
aliens[index].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.userShipBody.rawValue
aliens[index].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.userShipBody.rawValue
```

Hope this provides the answer to the question

EDIT: 
Here is a sample proj you can try on

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


let newDot1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
let newDot2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
var reset = false

enum categoryBit: UInt32 {
    case ball = 1
    case ball2 = 2

}



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -0.3)

    newDot2.setScale(0.3)
    newDot2.name = "dot1"
    newDot2.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)
    newDot2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: newDot2.size.width/2)
    newDot2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = categoryBit.ball.rawValue
    newDot2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = categoryBit.ball2.rawValue
    newDot2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = categoryBit.ball2.rawValue
    self.addChild(newDot2)


    newDot1.setScale(0.8)
    newDot1.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.minY)
    newDot1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: newDot1.size.width/2)
    newDot1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    newDot1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = categoryBit.ball2.rawValue
    newDot1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = categoryBit.ball.rawValue
    newDot1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = categoryBit.ball.rawValue
    newDot1.name = "dot2"
    self.addChild(newDot1)

}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    newDot2.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.maxY)



}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("contact made")


    let hitDot = contact.bodyB.node! as! SKSpriteNode
    let hitDot1 = contact.bodyA.node! as! SKSpriteNode
    if hitDot1.name == "dot1" || hitDot.name == "dot1" {
        reset = true
    }


}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if reset {
        newDot1.position.x = 0
        reset = false
    }
}


}
```

DELETE everything in GameViewController view didload method and add this

```
 super.viewDidLoad()

    let skview = self.view as! SKView


    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skview.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    skview.showsFPS = true
    skview.showsNodeCount = true
    skview.showsPhysics = true
    skview.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: I updated the code as shown but the results are the same.

Comment: //User Ship.
        for node in self.children           {
            if (node.name == "userShip")    {

                userShipSprite = node
    }
        //Set up user ship body for physics.
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        userShipSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.userShipBody.rawValue

    }

Comment: I don't know what you are doing there. Also found these. make usership an SKSpriteNode

Comment: var userShipSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "NAMEOFIMAGE")

Comment: I suggest you use minimum code. Create physics bodies and then check detection. Also. remove the for in loop for usership. Define the position of the ship and add thenship . Define it as an SKPhysicsbody

Comment: If u are using userinterface. Use childNode(withName: "userShip") to get the ship. Make sure u name it. Also u havent created physics bodies for alien and usership. Create SKPhysicsbody. eg ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (ball.size.width/2))

Comment: So put minimum code and I would tell you whats wrong. To start off. Make both SKSpritenodes. Put the physics contact delegate outside the loop(if u have one). create physicsbodies and define them. Give their category. And set the collision and contact bitmask.

Comment: I have given a working example in the answer EDIT section. Hope that helps. Goodluck with the game.

Comment: Hey Chip, so I tried a few of your methods but I'm getting an error when it comes to your edit of my GameViewController. super.viewDidLoad is "expecting a declaration" while the rest don't recognize the term "view", is this possibly a kit I have not imported? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Oh I think. The Gamescene was not porperly intended. Let me correct that. You should have the class GameScene in another swift file. Probably thats the error.

Comment: So try now. Copy gamescene class to a seperate swift file (got to add file and add an empty swift) Next delete everything in viewdidload method in GameViewController. Then add the code I gave. Should work. If you get errors let me know exactly what it says.